# Can't stop spring batch step

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

Can`t stop spring batch step..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <description>Example job to get you started. It provides a skeleton for a typical batch application.</description>
<bean id="HelloTasklet" class="c.c.c.HelloTasklet" scope="step"/>
<bean id="completionPolicy" class="org.springframework.batch.repeat.policy.DefaultResultCompletionPolicy"/> 
<bean id="chunkTimeout" class="org.springframework.batch.repeat.policy.TimeoutTerminationPolicy">
    <constructor-arg value="3"/>
</bean>
<bean id="commitCount" class="org.springframework.batch.repeat.policy.SimpleCompletionPolicy">
    <property name="chunkSize" value="200" />
</bean>
<bean id="chunkCompletionPolicy" class="org.springframework.batch.repeat.policy.CompositeCompletionPolicy">
    <property name="policies">
    <list>
        <ref bean="chunkTimeout" />
        <ref bean="commitCount" />
    </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="RandomChunkSizePolicy" class="c.c.c.RandomChunkSizePolicy"/>
<job id="importInvoices"  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">  
<listeners>
<listener ref="loggingListener"/>
</listeners>
    <step id="vehicleStep" next="hello">
    <tasklet>
        <chunk reader="vehicleReader"  writer="vehicleWriter" chunk-completion-policy="RandomChunkSizePolicy"/>
    </tasklet>
</step>
    <step id="hello" next="decompress">
        <tasklet ref="HelloTasklet" />
    </step>

    <step id="decompress" next="readWriteInvoices">
        <tasklet ref="decompressTasklet" />
    </step>
    <step id="readWriteInvoices">
        <tasklet>
            <chunk reader="reader" writer="writer" commit-interval="100" />
        </tasklet>  
    </step>
</job>
 <bean id="loggingListener" class="c.c.c.JobLoggerListener"></bean>
<bean id="decompressTasklet" class="c.c.c.DecompressTasklet">
    <property name="inputResource" value="file:./input/input.zip" /> 
    <property name="targetDirectory" value="./work/output/" /> 
    <property name="targetFile" value="invoices.txt" /> 
</bean>
<bean id="reader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">
    <property name="resource" value="file:./work/output/invoices.txt" />
    <property name="linesToSkip" value="1" />
    <property name="lineMapper">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
            <property name="lineTokenizer">
                <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                    <property name="names" value="INVOICE_ID,CUSTOMER_ID,DESCRIPTION,ISSUE_DATE,AMOUNT" />
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="fieldSetMapper">
                <bean class="c.c.c.InvoiceFieldSetMapper" /> 
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="writer" class="c.c.c.InvoiceJdbcItemWriter">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
</bean> 
</beans>
```

and see this in input:

```
The chunk size has been set to 2
Reader
Reader
Writer
[reeeeader, reeeeader]

The chunk size has been set to 2
Reader
Reader
Writer
[reeeeader, reeeeader]

The chunk size has been set to 2
Reader
Reader
Writer
[reeeeader, reeeeader]
```

..and so on. Need advice.

Comment: have you tried a simplest job and try to stop on that, so that you don't have bunch of irrelevant distracting config?

Comment: can you attache a sources for example.Thanks

Comment: It think it should be your responsibility doing that.  Just make a simplest reader which read from a text file, and a simplest writer writing to a very simple table.  Make chunk size 1.  Run it, then try to stop it.  If you can't even stop this, then you should actually look closer to the correct way stopping a job execution

Comment: Form what i understand, you job go on an infinite loop?  if so, then it is because your reader never return null when all the stuff to be read is done

Answer (score 6):

A step will only stop when it reads null values in its ItemReader implementation.You need to make sure that the reader implementation reads and returns null at some point of time. Then the step will stop on its own.